razor.g.cs file: The type or namespace name "Pages" does not exist in the namespace "MyApp.Client" in Components_Pages_Users_razor.g.cs
I have a Blazor class which I'm trying to include in a component with @inherits like so:
@page "/Users"
@inherits MyApp.Client.Pages.UsersBase
...

The Base class, UsersBase.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
namespace MyApp.Client.Pages
{
    public class UsersBase: ComponentBase
    {
           //...code...
    }
}

When I try compiling my project I get an error:

The type or namespace name "Pages" does not exist in the namespace "MyApp.Client" in Components_Pages_Users_razor.g.cs

The file, Components_Pages_Users_razor.g.cs, existed in the obj folder, so I tried both clearing the "bin" and "obj" files and rebuilding the solution. Neither solved the problem.
What is causing this?

I answered my own question. For some reason, my .csproj file removed the file and re-added it, like this:
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Components\Pages\UsersBase.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Components\Pages\UsersBase.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

Removing both of the above Item Groups from the .csproj file fixed the problem.
